# If $A^2 =0$ then possible rank of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let, $A$ be a non zero matrix of order $8$ with $A^2 =0.$ Then one of the possible value for rank of $A$ is
>
> (a) $5$ (b) $4$ (c) $6$  (d) $8$.

**Attempt :**

As , $A^2=0$ , so $A$ is a nilpotent matrix of order $2$. So , characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of the form $x^2f(x)$ , where $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $6$. So , possible values of $rank(A)$ are $4,5,6$.

Am I correct ?

Comment: If $A$ has a nonzero eigenvalue, can $A^2$ possibly be zero?  Hint: apply $A^2$ to the corresponding eigenvector.  Note: this doesn't necessarily help you solve your problem; see the answers below.  It's just your reasoning about the characteristic polynomial is also not correct.

Answer (score 6):

$Range(A)=\{Ax : x\in \mathbb{R}^8\}$

**Claim : $Range(A)\subset Ker(A)$**

Suppose $y=Ax\in Range(A)$

Then $Ay=A^2(x)=0$

$\implies y\in \ker (A)$

$\implies Range(A)\subset Ker(A)$

$\implies Rank(A)\leq Nullity (A)$

Therefore from Rank Nullity theorem We have

$dim (\mathbb{R}^8)=8=Rank(A)+Nullity(A)$

$\implies 8\geq Rank(A)+Rank(A) $

$\implies 4\geq Rank(A)$

And Therefore possible value of Rank(A) is $4$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $A^2 = 0$, what can you say about the null space and range of $A$?

Comment: How we define  a linear transformation?

Comment: A linear transformation is a special type of function, make sure you have learnt all the definitions and basic theory before you attempt to solve problems.

Comment: Left multiplication by a real $n \times n$ matrix is a linear transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

As the minimal polynomial of $A$, i.e. $m(A)/x^2$, it should be $x$ or $x^2$, but $x$ is not possible as $A$ is non zero. So $m(A)=x^2$

Its Jordan canonical form has 4 Jordan blocks of order 2, 1 block of order 2 and other 6 blocks of order 1, 2 block of order 2 and 4 block of order 1, 3 block of order 2 and 2 block of order 1, so rank must be 4.
And also i.e. 3,2,1,0

Answer (score 0):

Some more hints.

1. If $A$ has a nullspace of dimension $N$, then at most N dimensions vanish if you apply $A$ once.
2. Then you have the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply formula rank (A^k) > equal k rank(A)- (k-1).n
0> equal 2×rank(A)-(2-1).8 hence rank is less than 4 hence maximum possible rank is 4

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).